# Progress all the same Class found inside the DOM

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I want to turn off the display of all DIVs labeled `readerPanelsRight` in the `class` of the DIV element, but I am getting this error.

The page contains `readerPanelsRight` but I still get the "undefined" error. What is the problem?

```
function updateStyleWithClass(elmId, value) {
   var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(elmId);
   if (typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
       elem[0].style.display = value;
     }
 }

function tabShowing(tabID) {
    var classMatcher = /(?:^|\s)readerPanelsRight(?:\s|$)/;
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = els.length; i--;) {
        if (classMatcher.test(els[i].className)) {
            updateStyleWithClass(els[i], 'none');
        }
    }
    // Element ID is showing code here..
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="tabShowing('elementID_1')">button_1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="tabShowing('elementID_2')">button_2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="tabShowing('elementID_3')">button_3</a>

<div class="readerPanelsRight" id="elementID_1"></div>
<div class="readerPanelsRight" id="elementID_2"></div>
<div class="readerPanelsRight" id="elementID_3"></div>
```

Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: elem[0] is undefined
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `getElementsByClassName()`?

Comment: Where is the variable `elem` in your code? That error isn't for the code you posted.

Comment: I noticed that the code is missing with your message, I've updated it now, thank you. @Barmar

Comment: You could also use `document.querySelectorAll("div.readerPanelsRight")`

Comment: As @Barmar says, this is much more straight-forward as ```for (const elem of document.getElementsByClassName("readerPanelsRight")) { /* ...some code using `elem` ... */ }``` (or using `querySelectorAll(".readerPanelsRight")`).

Comment: I still don't see anything that uses `elem` as an array.

Comment: Re the updated code: You're passing an **element instance** into your function, but then using it as though it were a string (by passing it to `getElementById`).

Comment: The error message should have a line number in it. Which line is getting the error?

Comment: @Barmar Line: `elem.style.display = value;`

Comment: That error can't come from that line, there's no `elem[0]`.

Comment: I added the missing codes, sorry for my amateurism. @Barmar

Comment: Aim; I want to close all `readerPanelsRight` when the button is clicked and only keep the button's ID active Div. @Barmar

Comment: The function never uses the `tabID` variable.

Comment: Use `href="#"`, otherwise clicking on the link reloads the page.

Comment: I understand, I updated the codes, renewed with Class instead of ID. However, it still doesn't work. @Barmar

Comment: I've converted your code to a runnable snippet, and it doesn't get that error.

Comment: `elmId` is not a class name, it's the DOM element. Just do `elmId.style.display = value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Use `getElementsByClassName()` to get the elements to loop over, not `getElementsByTagId()`. And in `updateStyleWithClass()`, the argument is the element, you don't need to call another `get` function.

```js
function updateStyleWithClass(elem, value) {
  elem.style.display = value;
}

function tabShowing(tabID) {
  var els = document.getElementsByClassName('readerPanelsRight');
  for (var i = els.length; i--;) {
    updateStyleWithClass(els[i], 'none');
  }
  let selected_tab = document.getElementById(tabID);
  if (selected_tab) {
    updateStyleWithClass(selected_tab, "block");
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't give me the code directly. You suggested a solution idea to explain my mistake and correct my mistake. Just like the teacher, that was great... Thank you for your help & Greetings from Turkey @Barmar

Comment: I have one last request for your help. If the button is clicked, is it possible to add the code "btn-primary" to the clicked button? (Please click here)[https://pastebin.com/wFYNpiFQ] @Barmar

Comment: Pass `this` as a second argument in the `onclick`, then use `.classList.add("btn-primary")` on that parameter.